# Error using Spring AOP with Dynamic Proxy with JMS Template on Weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-jms, spring-amqp

I'm getting an error when I try to use in the same project Spring Template JMS to messaging to ActiveMQ and Spring AOP to auditing and handle exceptions on Weblogic 12.2.1. Error occurs on server startup.

If I config aspect to use CGLIB, I got exceptions from Weblogic, and I prefer, if it's possible to maintain using of Dynamic Proxy. Does anyone already had this problem or have any idea what could cause it?

**My aspect config class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
public class AspectConfig {

    @Bean
    public LoggingErrorAspect loggingErrorAspect(){
        return new LoggingErrorAspect();
    }
}
```

**Message Listener config class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
public class MessagingListenerConfig {

    @Autowired
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?>  jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
        return factory;
    }

}
```

**Stack:**

> weblogic.application.ModuleException:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean
>   named
>   'org.springframework.jms.config.internalJmsListenerEndpointRegistry'
>   is expected to be of type
>   'org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry' but was
>   actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy213'

Comment: I tried to change to RabbitMQ, but I got the same problem:

`weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'emailRabbitTemplate' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where you are injecting the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` (or `RabbitTemplate`) but you have to inject by interface when you proxy with JDK proxies.

Why are you advising the registry - what are you trying to achieve with that? It doesn't provide many interfaces so it can't be referenced once proxied, except by `DisposableBean` and `SmartLifecycle`.

The `RabbitTemplate` can be proxied but you need to inject `RabbitOperations`, not `RabbitTemplate`.

Comment: Gary, are there some way to define to aspect just work with specific classes? My main target using aspect is to handle general exceptions and auditing general operations.

Comment: You need to add a pointcut to your aspect to specify where you want it applied. See the javadocs for `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` and the [Spring Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

Comment: Thank you Gary Russel. I found solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it the problem. I had to change the broker to AMQP RabbitMQ, and I needed to use interface instead of classes in all my config. After it, startup load works and aspect too.

Here is Aspect Config and Messaging Config.

**AspectConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
public class AspectConfig {

    @Bean
    public LoggingErrorAspect loggingErrorAspect(){
        return new LoggingErrorAspect();
    }
}
```

**MessagingConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:/config/messaging.properties") })
@ComponentScan("br.com.aegea.scab.notification")
@lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
public class MessagingConfig {

    public static final String ERROR_QUEUE = "ERROR_QUEUE";
    public static final String EMAIL_QUEUE = "EMAIL_QUEUE";

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(environment.getProperty("spring.rabbitMQ.host"));
        connectionFactory.setUsername(environment.getProperty("spring.rabbitMQ.user"));
        connectionFactory.setPassword(environment.getProperty("spring.rabbitMQ.password"));
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitOperations emailRabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setRoutingKey(EMAIL_QUEUE);
        template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        listenerContainer.setQueueNames(EMAIL_QUEUE);
        listenerContainer.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        listenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageReceiver());
        listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        return listenerContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener messageReceiver() {
        return new MessageReceiver();
    }
}
```